# output numbers bold except some

Tags: php

How to produce the following output? All numbers should be bold except 10, 20, 30 and 40.

**1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9** 10 **11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19** 20 **21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29** 30 **31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39** 40

My current code is:

```
<?php

    $i = 1;

    while($i <= 40) {
        $m = ($i % 1);
        if($m == 0) {
            echo '<b><u>' . $i . '</b></u>';
        }
        $i++;
    }

?>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Can you show us what have you done so far to achieve desired output ?

Comment: Hint: You need somd condition that "decides" if a number is a multiple of 10. Ouput all numbers in bold except those divisible by 10. Have a look at the modulo operator `% ` at http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

Comment: Help us a little with what you have so far. It's better to teach you than just give you code

Comment: <?php
$i=1;

while($i<=40)
{
 $m=($i%1);
 if ($m==0)
 {
 
 echo '<b><u>'.$i.'</b></u>';
 }
 
 $i++;
 
}

?>

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Answer (score 0):

Simple one:

```
<?php
for ($i=1;$i<=40;$i++){
    if ($i % 10 == 0){
        $result .= $i;
    }
    else{
        $result .= "<b>".$i."</b>";
    }
}

echo $result;
?>
```

Update 1:

If your logic is to be corrected then,

```
<?php

    $i = 1;

    while($i <= 40) {
        $m = ($i % 10); // have to replace 1 by 10
        if($m == 0) {
            echo $i;
        }
        else{
            echo '<b><u>' . $i . '</b></u>';
        }
        $i++;
    }

?>
```

You can merge the `if ($i%10 == 0)` into single statement as well.

```
<?php 

$i=1; 

while($i<=40) 
{ 
    if ($i%10 == 0){
        echo $i; 
    }
    else{
        echo '<b><u>'.$i.'</b></u>'; 
    }
    $i++;
} 
?>
```

Comment: please can you quide me as I am really lost

Comment: @Anon123 you need to add your suggestions in comments instead of editing the post.

Comment: @Anon123 if the answer helped you please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

one small Correction From 1st answer @Fakhruddin Ujjainwala

Undefined variable: result

```
<?php
$result = "";
for ($i=1;$i<=40;$i++){
    if ($i % 10 == 0){
        $result .= $i;
    }
    else{
        $result .= "<b>".$i."</b>";
    }
}

echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks @stalinwesley its actually a `php notice` and can be ignored easily.