# PHP ERROR displaying numbers

Tags: php

please assist where I am going wrong:

I am trying just to get the numbers: 5, 15, 25, 35 in *bold* and *underlined*.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    for($i=1;$i<=40;$i++) {
        $m=($i%15);
        if($m==0) {
           echo '<b><u>' . $i . '</b></u>' ;
        }
        else{
           echo $i;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: You must end your tags correctly, like so: `<b><u> ' . $i . </u></b>'` - Please note that **SO is NOT** a free debug / fix-my-code service, do some research, follow a couple of tutorials and learn some basic php / htm, visit [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get a better idea of what SO is about.

Comment: Please accept the previous answer before asking new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35915054/php-coding-excersises

Comment: @Anon123 there is a `right sign` on left side of each answer. You need to tick it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your math, your condition with modulo 15 is true for 15, 30 and so on. If you need  5 15 25 35, then you are looking for odd numbers with modulo 5 == 0:

```
for($i=1;$i<=40;$i++) {
    if($i%5 == 0 && $i%2 == 1){
        echo '<b><u>' . $i . '</u></b>' ;
    }else{
        echo $i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

close tags correctly, like this,

```
for($i=1;$i<=40;$i++) {
    $m=($i%15);
    if($m==0){
       echo '<b><u>' . $i . '</u></b>' ;
    }
    else{
       echo $i;
    }
}
```

You did mistake here,

```
echo '<b><u>' . $i . '</b></u>' ;
```